# How to trigger the click from another component using useRef hook

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components where the `BoxComponent` holds the box items with click function where it shows the data of the clicked box in the page. In the `CarouselComponent`, I would like to trigger the box item click event either using the hook or a different method. I've also added `data-id` attribute on each carousel item similar ID from the `BoxComponent`.

I'm not expert in ReactJS and still learning. From my understanding, in cases like this we can use the hook `useRef` to store value. Is it correct?

Below is what I have done so far, but when clicking either one of those, the `data-id` doesn't update and I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError`.

Sample data:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 'test-01',
    value: { text: 'foo 01' }
  },
  {
    id: 'test-02',
    value: { text: 'foo 02' }
  },
  {
    id: 'test-03',
    value: { text: 'foo 03' }
  }
];
```

Sample `BoxComponent.js`

```js
const BoxComponent = () => {
  // The data updates on each box click containing id and value property.
  // [
  //   id: 'test-01',
  //   value: {} 
  // ]
  const { data } = useContext(BoxContext);

  const clickRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clickRef.current) {
      // From here I'd like to trigger the `onClickHandler`
      // when clicking the carousel item using the `clickRefHandler`.
      // However, the `clickRef.current` doesn't update where I'm expecting
      // to output the element depending on which item was clicked.

      // Clicking Button 1 should log test-01,
      // Clicking Button 2 should log test-02, and so on,
      // but the log only shows the first clicked button and doesn't update
      // and the actual data.id does update.

      // It also throws `Uncaught TypeError: clickRef.current.click is not a function`
      clickRef.current.click();
    }
  }, [data.id);

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    // Updates the data value.
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <div id='test-01' onClick={onClickHandler}>Button 1</div>
      <div id='test-02' onClick={onClickHandler}>Button 2</div>
      <div id='test-03' onClick={onClickHandler}>Button 3</div>
      <CarouselComponent clickRefHandler={clickRef}>
    </>
  );
}
```

Sample `CarouselComponent.js`

```js
const CarouselComponent = ({ clickRefHandler }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div data-id='test-01' ref={clickRefHandler}>Item 1</div>
      <div data-id='test-02' ref={clickRefHandler}>Item 2</div>
      <div data-id='test-03' ref={clickRefHandler}>Item 3</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Am I missing something or am I using a wrong hook? Please help.

Link to the codesandbox of the sample app:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-chatterjee-ko4zdh

Comment: I think you need forward ref instead. [https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: You should only give `ref` to a single element, in this case, it will just have access to the last element `Item 3`

I do think you are passing ref correctly, if you can share  a codesandbox link of your issue on which people can debug it would be great

Comment: @YashJoshi thank you for your reply. sure, I'll prepare the codesandbox and share the link here.

Comment: Hello @YashJoshi, I have included in the text area the link to codesandbox. Thank you!